# 1D Array, how to make rows and Columns C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, nested-loops, bubble-sort

I was wondering how I would write a one dimensional array with 10 elements into 2 rows and 5 columns? I am doing this to try to organize my bubbleSort method.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

const int NUM_ELEMENTS = 10;
void bubbleSort(int data[]){
    srand(time(0));
 int temp = 0;
 for(int i = 0; i<NUM_ELEMENTS;i++){
     data[i] = rand()%10;
     }
 for(int b = 0; b<NUM_ELEMENTS-1; b++){

    for(int x= 0; x<NUM_ELEMENTS-1;x++)
    {

     if(data[x]>data[x+1]){
      temp = data[x];
      data[x] = data[x+1];
      data[x+1] = temp;

     }

    }
 }
for(int i = 0; i<NUM_ELEMENTS; i++)    
printf("%4d",data[i]);   
}
int main()
{
int data[NUM_ELEMENTS];
bubbleSort(data); 
}
```

Comment: "organize my bubblerSort method"? Care to clarify?

Comment: It's about how you store/access elements from the array. `col + row * numOfCols`. And what's with the java tag?

Comment: Why would you do that? If you need a 2D array - just make it a 2D array.

Comment: @StillLearning I was trying to see if there was a way outside of making a 2D array. I understand how to do it for a 2D array.

Comment: @Emz When I said that I meant to not have all the elements being printed out on a single line. Rather, on two lines.

Comment: Well, then just handle the index as Vince mentioned in the comment above.

Comment: @VinceEmigh How would I go about implementing that into my current program? Such as how I would I use it within a loop? And sorry for the java tag, I took it off. First time asking a question on the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what your trying to do. Printing a one-dim array into a two-dim array.

```
int [] data = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    int rows = 2;
    int columns = 5;
    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < columns; column++) {
            System.out.printf("%d "+data[row * columns + column]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 
6 7 8 9 10
```

Comment: I switched it to fit the syntax of C++, but it worked perfectly, thank you.